# STM32 Build Error "cannot open linker script file" despite having it

Tags: c, compiler-errors, stm32

I am running STM32CubeIDE version 1.6.0 (which is writing in C) on a Windows 7 virtual machine running on Parallels. I am trying to "build" my code, but when I do I get an error that says:

```
cannot open linker script file \MAC\Home\Documents\STM32CubeIDE\A1\STM32L476RGTX_FLASH.ld: No such file or directory
```

I've checked and have found the file from both the mac and PC side of my computer. If I had to guess, the issue is that the link the program is looking for is

```
\MAC\Home\Documents\STM32CubeIDE\A1\STM32L476RGTX_FLASH.ld:
```

but the ACTUAL link is

```
\\MAC\Home\Documents\STM32CubeIDE\A1\STM32L476RGTX_RAM.ld
```

with TWO back slashes.

If anyone can help with this, I'd really appreciate it, I've also attached images below of the error and finding the file on both operating systems respectively in case it helps:[image: error message in program]

[image: finding the file in both operating systems]

Comment: In the Windows explorer, please show the full path. Also please show us the linker settings in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a fix but a workaround:  try mapping the shared directory `\\MAC` to a drive letter.

From [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/map-a-network-drive-in-windows-7-f5529cc1-5d09-89e5-c666-11e5d96229b0):

1. Select Start > Computer > Map Network Drive.
2. In the Drive list, select any available drive letter.
3. In the Folder box, type the path of the folder or computer, or select Browse to find the folder or computer. To connect every time you log on to your computer, select the Reconnect at logon check box.
4. Select Finish.